# How to set the DisplayRectangle property of a control (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, controls

I am designing a control where the user can specify the X, Y, Width and Height of the `DisplayRectangle` property in relation to the `ClientRectangle`.

From what I have read in the MSDN documentation, `DisplayRectangle` only has a get accessor, and therefore its dimensions cannot be set, however this is imperative in my control!

Can any one suggest how I might safely implement a `DisplayRectangle` that has both get and set accessors? - or explain why this is bad practice?

Thanks.

**TESTS:**

1. Set `TabControl` style to `UserPaint`, and adjust the `Alignment` property, The `DisplayRectangle` moves to compensate for the location of the tabs. Assuming `TabControl` has a built in mechanism to set the Rectangle bounds.
2. Created `DemoControl : Control`, painted `ClientRectangle` in Red, and `DisplayRectangle` in Blue and tried calling `SetDisplayRectLocation(x, y)`...not quite what I wanted...and yielded no results!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to allow the user to set the bounds of the DisplayRectangle property for a control, I have come up with the following solution:

```
public class ExtendedControl : Control
{
    private Rectangle displayRectangle;

    protected override Rectangle DisplayRectangle
    {
        get { return this.displayRectangle; }
    }

    public void SetDisplayRectangle(Rectangle rect)
    {
        this.displayRectangle = rect;
    }

    public ExtendedControl()
    {
        this.displayRectangle = base.DisplayRectangle;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not bad. But should note that the internal private variable of the base class will still not be set. Only the extended one. This might make a difference in the presentation.

Comment: @ouflak I think that's the point. You can't set the rectangle in the base class at all, so you have to manage its coordinates entirely, but there are plenty of APIs under the hood to help with this